# Will PCB assemblers solder wires to the board?

Tags: pcb, manufacturing

When preparing a medium run prototype, are there any manufacturers out there who will solder wires to you if you ask? For example, I have a device with 6 sensor pins. I'm hoping that a manufacturer, in the US or overseas, would be willing to solder 10 cm wire to each of these pins prior to shipment, to make manufacturing easier. Is this a typical request?

Comment: Why not? They will just include it in the price.

Comment: Is there any way to indicate this in a .brd or .sch file? Out of curiosity, is this an automated process, or will a human be doing it?

Comment: Wires? Probably a human. Well, if it's a large volume and the assembly is fully automated, they might not be willing to add a human to the process. not for a reasonable price at least.

Comment: Why not use connectors?

Comment: I've requested hand soldering in parts of some boards before and I provided not only drawings but a reference board which I assembled myself. Everything went alright.

Comment: connectors will be cheaper, but maybe not for your end-result of you have to hire folks to connect them...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that should be no problem with most contract manufacturers.  However, the only way to know if any one manufacturer will do this is to ask.  Generally manufacturers will perform a variety of tasks, including hand soldering when necessary.  Of course they will take the total task into account when quoting the job.  Generally though, it will be cheaper to have the CM hand-solder additional parts than for you to do it after receiving boards.

Of course all this needs to be properly specified in the documentation package you give the CM to quote on.  The board drawing should show where the wires go, how long they are, how to strip them, whether to tin the ends, etc.  If the process is complicated enough, you have a separate drawing for that.  Any manufacturer not set up to do that will just not provide a quote.

Answer (score 2):

Having wires and connectors attached facilitates testing.

Getting manufacturers to do basic testing is also a good idea, as you pay for working boards, and assembly quality issues have to be dealt with by them. When there are assembly issues, it is quick and easy for them to repair on the line compared to shipping them back to CN, long after the run was finished (or more realistically putting them on a shelf to fix "someday")

This means you making proper test jigs and processes for them to use, but that is also a very good thing to do up front.

You might find that the tested price is significantly above the untested price - but there is a good reason for that.

Comment: Yup, +1.  Creating a test jig is part of the development of a board or a new product.  All too often I see this left as a afterthought and not included in the original budget.  That's the most expensive way to go.  Field failures are very expensive.